Why do I get cURL Receive Error (Error Code 56)
I am using libcurl to make HTTPS requests from a device to a local test server. The test server seems to respond to other clients correctly, just not to this device. So, it probably does not have any proxy or firewall issues.
On the client side, the device is programmed with libcurl in C++ to make HTTPS requests to this server. It also has the server self-signed certificate added so that CURL does not throw any Untrusted Certificate errors. This client can communicate with other servers in the world without problem.
So, the test server is working well with other clients, the client also works well with other servers, but these two are not able to communicate with each other completely. In libcurl, I get error code 56 (CURLE_RECV_ERROR).
In the server side debugging info, I can see "GET HTTP/1.1 200" for each request, which means the server has done its job well!
The following image shows Wireshark records on the server side. (the server is running on 192.168.0.107:443). However, it seems that these records do not give any clues, at least to me:

The server is running simply with a Python script:
import http.server
import ssl
import logging
from io import BytesIO

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class HTTPRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        original_wfile = self.wfile
        self.wfile = BytesIO()
        super().do_GET()
        self.send_captured_response(original_wfile)

    def send_captured_response(self, original_wfile):
        response_body = self.wfile.getvalue()
        logging.info(f"Response body:\n{response_body.decode('utf-8')}")

        self.wfile = original_wfile
        self.wfile.write(response_body)

def create_server(server_class=http.server.HTTPServer, handler_class=HTTPRequestHandler, port=443):
    server_address = ('192.168.0.107', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    # Set up SSL context
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
    context.load_cert_chain('Path/To/certificate.pem', 'Path/To/private.key') 
    httpd.socket = context.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, server_side=True)
    return httpd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    httpd = create_server()
    logging.info("Serving HTTPS on port 443...")
    httpd.serve_forever()



This is the the server log after each request:
INFO:root:Serving HTTPS on port 443...
192.168.0.201 - - [17/Apr/2024] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:root:Response body:
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/3.11.5        
Date: Thu, 17 Apr 2024 
Content-type: text/html
Content-Length: 941
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Apr 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
The rest is simply an HTML content ...

On the other side, the client is running libcurl on a microcontroller. It utilizes the easy API. Mbedtls is used as SSL Library. As you see I disabled the certificate and host verfication, because I use self signed certificate in the server side.
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main() {
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://192.168.0.107:443");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L); // Disables host name verification
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L); // Diables Peer's certificate verfication
        
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        
        std::cout << "Curl Response Response Code: " << res << std::endl;
        
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    
        }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}


The following shows the libcurl logs:
* timeout on name lookup is not supported
*   Trying 192.168.0.107:443...
* Connected to 192.168.0.107 (192.168.0.107) port 443
* mbedTLS: Connecting to 192.168.0.107:443
* mbedTLS: Handshake complete, cipher is TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
* SSL connected
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.107
Accept: */*

* Closing connection
Curl Code: 56

In case of a successfull response, I would see the HTML content just before closing connection in libcurl logs.

The Wireshark screenshot only shows that a TLS connection is being made, exchanging some data, and then being closed. It does not show the actual HTTP traffic that is flowing through the TLS tunnel. Can you please show the HTTP traffic? And the libcurl code? And libcurl's debug logging? For all we know, the HTTP response is malformed in some way that is confusing libcurl. There is simply not enough information to diagnose your problem.

Thanks for your comment. I added some more information. However, I do not know how to decrypt HTTP trafic in wireshark. Because I am using libcurl from a microcontroller (not a Browser) I do not have access to SSL Key logs to add them to wireshark.

That's why I mentioned libcurl's own log, which can get you the traffic that is sent before being encrypted and received after being decrypted.
